# Can't set argument default value to a global variable?

Tags: php, variables

Why can't I do that?

```
function ($var1, $var2 = $GLOBALS['var']){
  ...
}
```

the global 'var' is a object

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't use variables as default values.
You can use this:

```
function ($var1, $var2 = null){
  if(is_null($var2))
      $var2=$GLOBALS['var'];
  ...
}
```

Comment: +1. Out of PHP docs: "The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call."

Answer (score 0):

Default parameter values for functions must be constants.

You can set it to a dummy value though like `null` and then at the beginning of your function replace the value.

```
function ($var1, $var2 = $GLOBALS['var']){
  if(is_null($var2))
      $var2=$GLOBALS['var'];
}
```